# Using a WrapBootstrap theme in an open source project

Tags: licensing, open-source, legal, mit-license, apache-license

I'm developing a desktop analytics application wrapped in Electron (that integrates with an external REST API), and am looking to use one of the WrapBootstrap themes to spruce it up.

I'm deciding between the MIT or Apache license for the project itself, which will be hosted on GitHub.

I'll be fronting the cost of the theme myself, and including it in the project's repository.

There are 3 different license "styles" listed: http://support.wrapbootstrap.com/knowledge_base/topics/usage-licenses

Both the Single and Multiple Application licenses indicate:

> - The item may not be redistributed or resold.

Does this restriction require me to purchase an Extended license for the above use?

Comment: Legal advice? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I can remove the "legal" tag, but it felt appropriate. Software licensing, however, *is* on topic.

Comment: Didn't you contact the support?

Comment: I have sent a message to their support team, no response yet, but was hoping to get some additional feedback here, in case anyone else has been in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the components that make up the item. For example, if you want a theme that contains GPL components, then their copyleft is viral. Which is one reason why copyleft is banned in many open source projects (such as Android). From a different perspective, the theme might have a component with some innocent-looking license that is actually legal-engineered to inflict some limitation of which you're not aware.

So I suggest to get the approval of the seller of the specific theme, and not just rely on the fact that the Extended license allows redistribution. There is some extra fine print on that license. I'm familiar with people who fell into IP-licensing honeypots and it ain't fun at all.

Either way, the non-Extended licenses are definitely not applicable in your case.